# Redirected Console Output from a Child Console Process to a Parent Console Process Fails

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, io-redirection

I have a console program as a parent process which runs several sub-processes which are also console programs. For the child processes, output is redirected to a pair of StringBuilder objects (one for STDOUT and one for STDERR.). Upon completion of a child process, its output is appended to the parent's output (also accrued in a pair of StringBuilder's.)

I recently added a new child process and it does not work. It doesn't fail either. I can't seem to debug it since no output statements in the child process work. I have spent a day trying to figure this out. Things are complicated a bit since the execution platform is on another server under control of the JAMS Scheduler.

Comment: Why post a question and answer it immediatly after yourself?

Comment: To share hard won knowledge.

Comment: Not ideal for StackOverflow though.

Answer (score 0):

The new child process used the most recent dotnet framework loaded on my development system - 4.6.1. The master process and the older child processes used 4.5.1. I verified using the dword "Release" at registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" that 4.6.1 was indeed installed on the server.

I changed the version of the new project to match the parent project (and other child projects), rebuilt and redeployed it and everything started working.

Hopefully, this will save one person a day of their life.